# Why does this keep outputting null and not working properly?

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

**Context: I am trying to create "Parrot" to which you set the age, a name and two phrases.**

After you provide the name to the parrot it will ask you what phrase you wish to teach him and then it will ask you the next phrase after that one.

When the parrot is born it is given a name and knows one phrase :"AWK! My name is ". Since it's a new parrot age is 0 and other 2 strings are empty

---

My code is the following, with a Parrot class and a ParrotRunner

## Parrot

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Parrot {

  private int age; 
  private String nameS;
  private String nameA;
  private String nameF = nameS + nameA;
  private String phrase2, phrase3;

    public Parrot(){
      age = 0;
      nameA = "Steve";
     phrase2 = "";
      phrase3 = "";

    }
    public Parrot(String na, int a , String p2, String p3){
       na = nameA;
       a = age;
       p2 = phrase2;
       p3 = phrase3;
    }
    public void setPhrase2(String p2){
       p2 = phrase2;
    }
    public void setPhrase3(String p3){
       p3 = phrase3;
    }
    public void setName(String na){
        na = nameA;
    }
    public void presetPhrases(String nf, String ns){
        nameF = nf;
        nameS = ns;
    }  
    public void setAge(int a){
       a = age;
    }
    public String getName(){
      return nameA;
    }
    public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }

    public String getPhrase2(){
      return phrase2;
    }
    public String getPhrase3(){
      return phrase3;
    }
    public String getNameS(){
    return "AWWWWWK! My name is ";
    }
    public String getNameF(){
        return getNameS() + getName();
    }

    public String toStringIntroduction(){
      return "AWWWWK! I'm " + getAge() + getNameF() + ". What do you wish me to say?";
    }
    public String toString2(){
      return getPhrase2() +"! What's the other phrase?";

    }
    public String toString3(){
      return getPhrase3();
    }
}
```

## ParrotRunner

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParrotRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Parrot basic = new Parrot();

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a; String p2, p3, na;

        System.out.println("Provide a name");
            na = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the age: ");
             a = input.nextInt();

        p2 = input.nextLine();
        p3 = input.nextLine();
      Parrot parameters = new Parrot( na,  a,  p2,  p3);
      System.out.println(parameters.toStringIntroduction());
      p2 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println(parameters.toString2());
      p3 = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println(parameters.toString3());

    }

}
```

The code in question keeps outping this wrong output which is the following and I have not been able to debug it after hours of checking and changing my code

```
ParrotRunner.main({ });
    Provide a name
        Name
    Enter the age: 
        1

    AWWWWK! I'm 0AWWWWWK! My name is null. What do you wish me to say?
        Hi
    null! What's the other phrase?
        Hi
    null
```

I would be very grateful if you all would help and please explain the null

Comment: Just one question: have your tried debugging your code? Single step through the program and see how the variables change. Probably you'll find out what went wrong, and then you have learned something. Much better than others telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Parrot(String na, int a , String p2, String p3){
    na = nameA;
    a = age;
    p2 = phrase2;
    p3 = phrase3;
}
```

should be the other way round:

```
public Parrot(String na, int a, String p2, String p3){
    nameA = na;
    age = a;
    phrase2 = p2;
    phrase3 = p3;
}
```

You don't want to override argument values, you want to use them for setting the fields. Make sure to correct the setters as well.

If you find it confusing, use `this` before the field name - it should always appear on the left side of an assignment:

```
this.nameA = na;
```

Comment: Same for the setter methods, except setPhrases. setPhrases is correct.

Comment: I always read `nameA = na` as "nameA becomes na". Perhaps that helps you remember the proper direction.